# SVN update does not work

Tags: svn

An SVN question.

Everything seems to be working fine, svn supports 4 servers, an all is dandy... however... sometimes it misses modifications in the files.

`svn up` is performed and it updates say 5 files while there were 6 files in the commit. I check svn status and info and there it nothing wrong. Revision is as it should be, also on a file that was missed in the revision.

When I delete the file manually and do svn up again it updates to proper, new version.

What may be the reason? Is it something I am doing wrong?

PS. I forgot to add that this happens randomly on one of the 4 servers never on all of them at the same time.

Comment: Which version of SVN do you use as client/server? Are you using IDE's in relationship with that or only plain svn client (command line?) or do you use TortoiseSVN client or others?

Comment: Hi,
On the development machine there is a mix of NetbeansIDE + Subversion plugin and Tortoise SVN (sometimes I use one sometimes the other). On the servers there is just a linux distribution of subvesrion used from command line. 
NetBeans Subvesrion: 1.17.1.42.1
Tortoise SVN: 1.6.16 64bit, with Subversion 1.6.17
Servers: no idea how to check... :)

Comment: BTW: What do you mean by "4 servers" ? Do you have four different SVN Servers?

Comment: No. 4 servers simply have svn checkout on them to allow for svn up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that your files in your working folder are not locked by another application.